# Is $\mathbb{P}\left[Z\leq z\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[Z=z\right]$?

Tags: probability

I do not if I have to ask.

If $Z$ is a discrete random variable with exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$. What is $\mathbb{P}\left[Z=z\right]$?

I know that $\mathbb{P}\left[Z\leq z\right]=1-e^{-\lambda z}$. So I guess $\lambda$. What is $\mathbb{P}\left[Z=z\right]$ is also $1-e^{-\lambda z}$?

EDIT: Thanks to johnniac for his help. I am answering my question.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}[Z = z]$ is the probability that the random variable $Z$ takes the value exactly $z$, and $\mathbb{P}[Z \leq z]$ is the probability that $Z$ takes some value at most $z$. Note that an exponentially distributed random variable is a continuous one, not a discrete one, so $\mathbb{P}[Z = z] = 0$ for all $z$ for exponentially distributed $Z$.

Comment: Try to find $P[z_0 < Z<z_0 +\delta] $ by integrate the PDF of exponential distribution, and then set $\delta \rightarrow 0 $.

Comment: Thank you G. Bach very much for your help.
@johnniac Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, $\mathbb{P}\left[z_0\leq Z \leq z_0+\epsilon\right]=F(z_0+\epsilon)-F(z_0)=e^{-\lambda z_0}-e^{-\lambda(z_0+\epsilon)}.$

Now, $$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\,\to\,0}\mathbb{P}\left[z_0\leq Z \leq z_0+\epsilon\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[Z=z_0\right]=e^{-\lambda z_0}-e^{-\lambda(z_0+0)}=0.$$